# I am trying to execute a script that pushes to git every x minutes as a service, but git uses 100% CPU and high amounts of RAM

Tags: shell-script, systemd, raspberry-pi, raspbian, git

I am trying to execute a script that pushes to git every x minutes as a service, but git uses 100% CPU and high amounts of RAM while seemingly doing nothing. (I checked after 8 minutes and it was still going)

When I execute the script manually it works perfectly and takes only a few seconds.

backupToGit.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/pi/<Projectfolder>
cat /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
while true
do
        git add *
        git commit -m "auto backup"
        echo "------------Starting to push to Github------------"
        git push git@github.com:JustLokust/<Projectname> master
        echo "------------Finished pushing to Github------------"
        sleep 300
done
```

Service:

```
[Unit]
Description=<Service Name>

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/<Projectfolder>
ExecStart=/home/pi/<Projectfolder>/backupToGit.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Why do you think it's using a lot of RAM? Is it because of the memory stat in `systemctl status`, or something else?

Comment: @ChrisDown I used the ```top``` command to check usage and saw that git was using around 300MB RAM it also randomly spikes to 300 CPU usage on a QuadCore with some other applications running.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Unix.se.  I see you use the <something> notation: be sure it is just when posting here, and that you instead use "something" instead in the script and the command lines. < and > are special to the shell and redirect stdin and stdout (which could explain the pb: if git instead works on the whole /home/pi folder ?)

Comment: Do you only have 1 git running? and which one is it? : `ps -ef  | grep "git" | grep -v "grep"` should tell you which one(s) is currently running

Comment: @OlivierDulac Yes, the notation is only used for the Post and is exchanged for the actual Project- and Foldername in the code.

Comment: Yes I only have one git running (using ```ps -ef | grep "git"``` ) but adding ``` | grep -v "grep" ``` doesn't give an output at all. If you are referring to the git Version it is 2.20.1
EDIT: if I activate the service there are multiple running and adding said above does also return results

Comment: @OlivierDulac It just stopped showing me the different versions and actually finished pushing which I don't really understand because it didn't do this for the whole day. Is there maybe a maximum amount of push commands in a certain timeframe?

Comment: @ErikBugdol : sorry, I didn't start using git yet (I shall do this within a few days...). You should ask another question for this, with a [git] tag, probably on stackoverflow . make sure you "git"-ed only what you thought you would (ie, make sure the script really updates the projectfolder you inteded to, and didn't do anything strange instead, or uploaded more (such as the parent folder?)).  And I'm quite sure big sites (gitlab or github) probably dislike being pushed every 300 seconds (especially if there are no changes...)

Comment: @OlivierDulac I think I just found the Solution myself:
The Service was only setuo to start the script which would run in an endless loop, but never to stop the script. this probably resulted in the script running one more time for every time I started / restarted the Service leading to an overlap in git instances and high Resource usage.
So: your Idea did help me in the end by showing me, that there are indeed multiple instances of git running. Therefore Thank You!

Comment: @ErikBugdol: glad you found out (that's why I suspected that ps -ef | grep git | grep -v grep may show multiple instances running in parrallel ...)/ when you take out the grep -v grep : you sometimes display the "grep git" instead, when no other git is running... You should always include `| grep -v grep` for those inquiries unless you need to see the grep lines themselves

Comment: Please post how you fixed it as an answer,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I just found the Solution myself with the Help of @OlivierDulac :

The Service was only setup to start the script which would run in an endless loop, but never to stop the script. this probably resulted in the script running one more time for every time I started / restarted the Service leading to an overlap in git instances and high Resource usage.

This ultimately blocked the execution of the script.

What you need to do to Reproduce the fix: Restart your server or kill all the Remaining Processes that run the looping script.

Comment: Good practice is to use "pid" files (usually /var/run/somename.pid) and check at the beginning of the script if : the file exist, and the pid listed is indeed running the same service : in that case, do not do anything and say another is running. If it is empty, or if the pid is not present (or is not the command it is supposed to be) : you can start a new instance (and write its pid, $$, into /var/run/somename.pid) . and the stop script should: kill the pid listed in that file (IF it is the commandline it is supposed to be), and if successful delete the file.